# Snapshot differences XCode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, snapshot

I created a snapshot in xcode 4.2. Now I want to see the preview dialog that displays differences between the current version of the project and the snapshot version. Where can I find that dialog. I'm lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, better late than never, but simply say "Restore snapshot" and select one, and it will show you a list of files that have changed, select one and it will show you the line differences.

Comment: I tried saying "Restore Snapshot" -- even said it really loud a couple of times.  Then I looked on the "File" menu and it was there, near the bottom.  ;-)  Thanks, Apple!

Comment: And a hearty hardy-har-har to you, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Version Editor to see the differences.